# Quartus Prime Lite Failed to find INSTANCE

Tags: vhdl, intel, quartus

I've tryed to run a simulation with ModelSim on Quartus Prime Lite but I've got this error messages:

Error (suppressible): (vsim-SDF-3250) Counter_6_1200mv_85c_vhd_slow.sdo(0): Failed to find INSTANCE '/i1'.

Error (suppressible): (vsim-SDF-3894) : Errors occured in reading and resolving instances from compiled SDF file(s).

Error (suppressible): (vsim-SDF-3250) Counter_6_1200mv_85c_vhd_slow.sdo(0): Failed to find INSTANCE '/i1'

It doesn't matter which code I'm running. The compilation was succesfull and the simulation path is right.

```
-- The code.
-- ADC reader: reads data from ADXL345

library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity g_reader is port (
    clk_50: in std_logic;   -- 50 MHz clock

    reset_n : in std_logic; -- reset signal (active low)

    -- SPI interface
    CS_N : out std_logic;   -- connected to chip select of g sensor
    SCLK : out std_logic;   -- spi clock
    SDIO : inout std_logic; -- spi data (bidirectional)

    -- data output
    dataX : out std_logic_vector(12 downto 0);
    dataY : out std_logic_vector(12 downto 0);
    dataZ : out std_logic_vector(12 downto 0)
);
end g_reader;


architecture behavior of g_reader is
    signal SCLK_counter : integer := 0;         -- starts clock
    signal SCLK_1 : std_logic;                  -- 1 MHz clock

    constant half_period : time := 10 ns;

begin

    -- SCLK
    process(clk_50)
    begin

        if (falling_edge(clk_50)) then

            if (SCLK_counter <= 24) then
                SCLK_1 <= '0';
            else 
                SCLK_1 <= '1';
            end if;

            if (SCLK_counter >= 49) then
                SCLK_counter <= 0;
            else
                SCLK_counter <= SCLK_counter + 1;
            end if;

        end if;

    end process;

    CS_N <= '0';
    SCLK <= '0';
    dataX <= "0000000000000";
    dataY <= "0000000000000";
    dataZ <= "0000000000000";


end behavior;
```

The testbench:

```
LIBRARY ieee;                                               
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

ENTITY g_reader_vhd_tst IS
END g_reader_vhd_tst;
ARCHITECTURE g_reader_arch OF g_reader_vhd_tst IS
-- constants     
constant half_period : time := 10 ns;                                            
-- signals              
signal clk : std_logic := '0';                                     
SIGNAL clk_50 : STD_LOGIC;
SIGNAL CS_N : STD_LOGIC;
SIGNAL dataX : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(12 DOWNTO 0);
SIGNAL dataY : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(12 DOWNTO 0);
SIGNAL dataZ : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(12 DOWNTO 0);
SIGNAL reset_n : STD_LOGIC;
SIGNAL SCLK : STD_LOGIC;
SIGNAL SDIO : STD_LOGIC;
COMPONENT g_reader
    PORT (
    clk_50 : IN STD_LOGIC;
    CS_N : OUT STD_LOGIC;
    dataX : OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(12 DOWNTO 0);
    dataY : OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(12 DOWNTO 0);
    dataZ : OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(12 DOWNTO 0);
    reset_n : IN STD_LOGIC;
    SCLK : OUT STD_LOGIC;
    SDIO : INOUT STD_LOGIC
    );
END COMPONENT;
BEGIN
    i1 : g_reader
    PORT MAP (
-- list connections between master ports and signals
    clk_50 => clk_50,
    CS_N => CS_N,
    dataX => dataX,
    dataY => dataY,
    dataZ => dataZ,
    reset_n => reset_n,
    SCLK => SCLK,
    SDIO => SDIO
    );
init : PROCESS                                               
-- variable declarations                                     
BEGIN                                                        
        -- code that executes only once                      
WAIT;                                                       
END PROCESS init;    

clk_proc : process  
begin                                                     
    clk <= not clk after half_period;
end process clk_proc;         

end g_reader_arch;
```

Comment: Well if you want us to help then you'll have to provide your testbench and vhdl code as this is unanswerable in this state.

Comment: I added the code into the post.

Comment: Your design and testbench analyze, elaborate and simulate without an SDF file which isn't supplied and apparently doesn't match. Was it generated for a post synthesis gate level model?

Comment: Thank you. Yes gate level simulation. I found this link: https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/programmable/support/support-resources/knowledge-base/solutions/rd05152000_7434.html but I don't understand which SDF File I need.

Comment: How I can find the SDF File?

Comment: Just want to say that I've fixed the bug :) The testbench wasn't the top entity and the ports of  component's hasn't the same order like the entity.